# Allow caching of share - roaming profiles - WS2016

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, best-practices, roaming-profile

I have a WS2016 that is running roaming profiles for users. Within the SMB file share, the option: "Allow caching of share" is enabled and was enabled by accident upon creation. There are already working profiles running, but I'd like to go back and simply untick the box to disallow this as it's against recommendations to have caching of roaming profile shares.

Any advice in regards to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have unchecked that at a few of my customers where they had it enabled and profiles were already being used. I have never had any issues afterwards.